# How to get every word after the Nth in an input in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get every word after the 2nd in my program. If I do

```
inputhere.split()[2]
```

I only get the 2nd word in the input, not every word after the 1st. How can I get every word after the 1st?

Comment: Did you not read the part about slicing in the Python tutorial?

Comment: Try `inputhere.split()[2:]`

Comment: try  this to print all values from 2nd index to last index  inputhere[2:]

Answer (score -1):

Use a `[i:]` to slice your list at a position `i`: [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

```
inputhere.split()[2:]
```